# Desktop directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu-one, python3, sublime-text

I'm trying to run a Python script using the Desktop directory but it's not working. It instead outputs "bash: ./s.py: Permission denied"
In the said script on top I put "#!/usr/bin/python3"
How do I go about this? L

Comment: Did you remember to make the file executable (`chmod +x s.py`)?

Comment: @steeldriver   thanks for the insight. I hadn't done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a python file, use the command `python3 filename.py`. You don't need to change permissions or add the line "#!/usr/bin/python3" to the file if you use this method.